# Overriding templates using "getParent()" doesn't seem to work

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I'm new to Symfony2 and i'm following the tutorial on YouTube Tutorial for the Symfony FOSUserBundle (FTW!).

Around min 7.40 or so, it says to add a method called getParent(), in my case

```
<?php
//src\Monse\UserBundle\UserBundle.php

namespace Monse\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class UserBundle extends Bundle{

    public function getParent(){

        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

my layout.html.twig looks like this

```
{# src\Monse\UserBundle\Resources\views\layout.html.twig #}
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
{{block('fos_user_content')}}
{% endblock %}
```

sadly, it doesn't work, and i've got no idea what i'm doing wrong. 
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you enabled your bundles in the kernel?

```
<?php
// app/AppKernel.php

public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        // ...
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        new Monse\UserBundle\UserBundle(),
    );
}
```

EDIT : You could rename your bundle MonseUserBundle to be able to distinguish the parent FOSUserBundle from the bundle that overrides it:

```
<?php
//src\Monse\UserBundle\MonseUserBundle.php

namespace Monse\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class MonseUserBundle extends Bundle{

    public function getParent(){

        return 'FOSUserBundle';
        }
    }
```

And now use this:

```
<?php
    // app/AppKernel.php

    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            // ...
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new Monse\UserBundle\MonseUserBundle(),
        );
    }
```

Comment: Hi, yes i did that. Ironically, it worked with no apparent reason. I have no idea what i was. Thank for your help

Comment: I got an error at the exact same position of the video. Unfortunately I couldn't solve it until now. Any further ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Actually this solves it (from original documentation):

```
{# src\Monse\UserBundle\Resources\views\layout.html.twig #}
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
{% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: version 2.3.1 (min chars for comment)

Comment: Okay, my question was based on 2.0.x